# Clock Puzzle problem

Tags: logical-deduction

[image]

Today I came across this puzzle:

> How many minutes is it until six o'clock if fifty minutes ago it was
> four times as many minutes past three o'clock?

Any help?

Comment: This question seems a bit *too* specific...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now, we have $x$ minutes left until 6 o'clock. 50 minutes ago, it was $4x$ minutes past 3 o'clock. That means that the time between 3 o'clock and 6 o'clock, 180 minutes, is equal to the sum of those times. In other words

$$\begin{align}
  4x + 50 + x & = 180 \\
  x & = \frac{180 - 50}{5} \\
  x & = 26
\end{align}$$

So it's now 26 minutes until 6 o'clock, or 34 minutes past 5.

Comment: Well-reasoned.  Short, and to the point.